# Generate series for week number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following `generate_series` -

```
 SELECT generate_series ('2017-01-01'::date, '2021-08-01'::date, interval '1 week')
```

It produces results like this -

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00-06
2017-01-08 00:00:00-06
2017-01-15 00:00:00-06
```

How do I get this query to produce this result instead -

```
2017_01
2017_02
2017_03
```

The `01`, `02` and `03` mean week 1, week 2 and week 3 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the date with to show the week number

```
SELECT to_char(dt, 'iyyy_iw') 
from generate_series ('2017-01-01'::date, '2021-08-01'::date, interval '1 week') as t(dt)
```

Note that I used the ISO week and year formatting which will yield e.g. `2016-52` for the first date. If you want a non-standard week numbering use the format mask `'yyyy_ww'`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select concat('2017_', lpad(n::text, 3, '0'))
from generate_series(1, 3, 1) gs(n);
```

In other words, given the problem you have specified, you don't need to deal with dates.  You can just append sequential numbers to the year.

Comment: But I have 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020 and 2021 data.

Comment: Also, this is giving me this error - `function lpad(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist`.

Comment: It seems there's a bit of information missing from your original question.  The question you posed is related to generating a year+week string, but you seem to have actual data that you need to do something with -- are you comparing your generated strings with the dates in your data?  What do you need to do with the year+week combination?

Comment: and what version of postgres are you using?

Comment: @Aaron . . . This answers the question that was actually asked.